# How can I extract and display images from web scraped data in R using rvest package?

Tags: r, web-scraping, web

I am currently trying to scrape the names and logos of all the Law Schools in the U.S. from a wiki page. I was able to create a table of university names and image links. However, I would like to create a table of university names with the actual images. I am using R programming.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
\###Reading in the Data
url = 
'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_law_schools_in_the_United_States'
school_url = 
'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_law_schools_in_the_United_States' 
   %\>%
read_html() %\>%
html_elements('.wikitable a') %\>%
html_attr('href')
school_url = paste('https://en.wikipedia.org/', school_url, sep='')

top3_school_urls = head(school_url, 3)

###Web Scraper
results = list()
for (school_url in top3_school_urls) {
  message('Scraping URL: ', school_url)
  school_html = read_html(school_url) 
  School = school_html %>% 
    html_element('h1 .mw-page-title-main') %>% html_text2()
  Logo = school_html %>% html_element('.infobox-image a') %>% 
          html_attr('href')
  Logo = paste('https://en.wikipedia.org/', Logo, sep='')

  school_tibble = tibble(School, Logo)
  results[[school_url]] = school_tibble
}

d = bind_rows(results, .id = 'url')
d`
```

I read the data into R and parsed the data using the `rvest` package. I was able to extract the links to the image but I would like to take it a step further and have the actual images in the table.

Comment: When you say you want to actually have the image, do you mean you want to embed it using the url or do you mean you want to download it and then use the local copy.  FYI unless somewhere has said it is okay (Wiki Commons does) it's not nice to use their bandwidth to store and render images for your page.   Is this page using markdown or html?

Comment: I want to download it and store a local copy. I'm not trying to display it on a web page.

Comment: I am parsing HTML data

Comment: No, I mean the page you want to display this in, what format is that being reated in?

Comment: You will have to use the download() function.

Comment: I want to save and display this in a markdown file. Ideally have it in a pdf.

Comment: The Rmarkdown for this would be ![alttext](full/path/to/local/file)  .. or you can put the url, depending on the format you are rendering to.

Answer (score 1):

One quick and easy option is `kableExtra`:

````
---
title: "law schools"
output: html_document
---
```{r echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(rvest)
  library(stringr)
  library(purrr)
  library(dplyr)
  library(kableExtra)
})

mw_api <- list(page  = "https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/html/",
               media = "https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/media-list/")

top_3 <- read_html(paste0(mw_api$page, "List_of_law_schools_in_the_United_States")) %>% 
  # extract link elements only from 2nd column of the table
  html_elements("table.wikitable tbody tr > td:nth-child(2) > a") %>% 
  # keep only top 3
  head(3) %>% 
  # get link / wiki title and link text from single elements
  map(~ tibble::tibble_row( wikititle = html_attr(.x, "href") %>% str_remove("^./"),
                            title = html_text(.x) %>% str_trim())
  ) %>% list_rbind() %>% 
  # request media list for titles
  mutate(logo = map_chr(wikititle, ~ paste0(mw_api$media,.x) %>% 
                          jsonlite::read_json() %>% 
                          pluck("items", 1, "srcset", 1, "src")),
         logo = paste0("https:", logo))

top_3 %>% 
  mutate(logo = "") %>% 
  kbl(booktabs = T) %>%
  kable_paper(full_width = FALSE) %>%
  column_spec(3, image = top_3$logo)

top_3
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   wikititle                title                    logo                        
#>   <chr>                    <chr>                    <chr>                       
#> 1 Birmingham_School_of_Law Birmingham School of Law https://upload.wikimedia.or…
#> 2 Cumberland_School_of_Law Cumberland School of Law https://upload.wikimedia.or…
#> 3 Samford_University       Samford University       https://upload.wikimedia.or…
```
````

Renders as:
[image]

When rendering to pdf, files must be downloaded first:

```r
dir.create("tmp_img/")
# Download all files listed in top_3$logo and updated 
# logo to include local files paths instead of urls
top_3 <- top_3 %>% 
  mutate(logo = map_chr(logo, ~ {
    destfile = file.path("tmp_img", basename(.x))
    download.file(.x, destfile = destfile, mode = "wb")
    destfile
    }))

top_3 %>% 
  mutate(logo = "") %>% 
  kbl(booktabs = T) %>%
  # we can use "scale_down" for slightly better fit, but most likely  
  # it needs some further tweaking
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("scale_down")) %>%
  column_spec(3, image = top_3$logo)
```

Comment: Why do i receive this error"Warning: URL '//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/49/Bsol.jpg': status was 'URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL'Error in `map_chr()`:"

Comment: Just tested and files were downloaded just fine. Did you change anything? Mediwiki API returns media links without `https:`-part, but `mutate` in the first block ( `mutate( ... , logo = paste0("https:", logo)` ) takes care of it.

Comment: When I copy and paste it into R Studio I receive these two errors "Package pdftex.def Error: File `https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/49/Bsol.jpg' not found: using draft setting.

Error: LaTeX failed to compile m.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See m.log for more info.
Execution halted"

Comment: Firts block works only for HTML and I'd recommend to start with that. When switching output to PDF, 2nd block must be included too, it downloads files and changes replaces logo URLs with local paths. kable calls for pdf and HTML are also different, so make sure you don't have both variants in your markdown.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I was able to get it to work. I had both variants in my markdown and that was what was causing the error